# Convert CSV values to datetime and create function from that in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, datetime

I have tried searching other posts on here, but can't seem to solve this problem. I have a CSV file in which Year, Crash_Month, Crash_Day and Crash_Time are all seperate columns in the CSV 'data_dict'. I am trying to solve the below question. How would I go about this? I have tried to use a data frame, and pandas convert to datetime, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Many thanks

Here's the data frame I'm trying to assign datetime to

```
    year  month  day       time
0   2000      1    1   4:30:59 
1   2000      1    1   0:07:35 
2   2000      1    1   4:51:37 
3   2000      1    1   4:27:56 
4   2000      1    1   2:16:31 
5   2000      1    1   0:37:21 
6   2000      1    1   0:52:57 
7   2000      1    1   3:35:14 
8   2000      1    1   2:41:58 
9   2000      1    1   3:43:02 
10  2000      1    1   3:49:19 
11  2000      1    1   3:03:55 
12  2000      1    1   4:46:01 
13  2000      1    1   1:07:24 
14  2000      1    1   8:29:04 
15  2000      1    1   6:35:21 
16  2000      1    1   6:06:25 
17  2000      1    1   7:10:13 
18  2000      1    1   10:57:24 
19  2000      1    1   7:54:38
```

So far, I have coded this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': (data_dict['Year']),
                   'month': (data_dict['Crash_Month']),
                   'day': (data_dict['Crash_Day']),
                   'time': (data_dict['Crash_Time'])})

date=pd.to_datetime(df[["year", "month", "day", "time"]],format='%YYYY%mm%dd, %HH%MM%SS')
print(date)

day_of_week = {0 : 'Monday',
              1: 'Tuesday',
              2: 'Wednesday',
              3: 'Thursday',
              4: 'Friday',
              5: 'Saturday',
              6: 'Sunday'}

month_season= {1: 'Summer',
              2: 'Summer',
              3: 'Autumn',
              4: 'Autumn',
              5: 'Autumn',
              6: 'Winter',
              7: 'Winter',
              8: 'Winter',
              9: 'Spring',
              10: 'Spring',
              11: 'Spring',
              12: 'Summer'}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data? 5 rows will do

Comment: Hi @nickp please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247).  [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be downvoted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: Heres the first few rows of the CSV file

Comment: Index,Age,Year,Crash_Month,Crash_Day,Crash_Time,Road_User,Gender,Crash_Type,Injury_Severity,Crash_LGA,Crash_Area_Type
1,37,2000,1,1,4:30:59,PEDESTRIAN,MALE,UNKNOWN,1,MARIBYRNONG,MELBOURNE
2,22,2000,1,1,0:07:35,DRIVER,MALE,ADJACENT DIRECTION,1,YARRA,MELBOURNE
3,47,2000,1,1,4:51:37,DRIVER,FEMALE,ADJACENT DIRECTION,0,YARRA,MELBOURNE
4,70,2000,1,1,4:27:56,DRIVER,MALE,ADJACENT DIRECTION,1,BANYULE,MELBOURNE
5,16,2000,1,1,2:16:31,PASSENGER,MALE,OPPOSING DIRECTION,0,MONASH,MELBOURNE

Comment: Here's the data frame I'm trying to assign datetime to

Comment: year,month,day,time
2000,1,1,4:30:59
2000,1,1,0:07:35
2000,1,1,4:51:37
2000,1,1,4:27:56
2000,1,1,2:16:31
2000,1,1,0:37:21
2000,1,1,0:52:57
2000,1,1,3:35:14
2000,1,1,2:41:58
2000,1,1,3:43:02
2000,1,1,3:49:19
2000,1,1,3:03:55
2000,1,1,4:46:01
2000,1,1,1:07:24
2000,1,1,8:29:04
2000,1,1,6:35:21
2000,1,1,6:06:25
2000,1,1,7:10:13
2000,1,1,10:57:24
2000,1,1,7:54:38

Comment: @Datanovice done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.zfill` and string concenation with `pd.to_datetime` to build up your datetime.

```
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['year'].astype(str) 
               + df2['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
               + df2['day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
               + ' '
               + df2['time'].astype(str),format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
              )

    year  month  day       time                date
0   2000      1    1   4:30:59  2000-01-01 04:30:59
1   2000      1    1   0:07:35  2000-01-01 00:07:35
2   2000      1    1   4:51:37  2000-01-01 04:51:37
3   2000      1    1   4:27:56  2000-01-01 04:27:56
4   2000      1    1   2:16:31  2000-01-01 02:16:31
5   2000      1    1   0:37:21  2000-01-01 00:37:21
6   2000      1    1   0:52:57  2000-01-01 00:52:57
7   2000      1    1   3:35:14  2000-01-01 03:35:14
8   2000      1    1   2:41:58  2000-01-01 02:41:58
9   2000      1    1   3:43:02  2000-01-01 03:43:02
10  2000      1    1   3:49:19  2000-01-01 03:49:19
11  2000      1    1   3:03:55  2000-01-01 03:03:55
12  2000      1    1   4:46:01  2000-01-01 04:46:01
13  2000      1    1   1:07:24  2000-01-01 01:07:24
14  2000      1    1   8:29:04  2000-01-01 08:29:04
15  2000      1    1   6:35:21  2000-01-01 06:35:21
16  2000      1    1   6:06:25  2000-01-01 06:06:25
17  2000      1    1   7:10:13  2000-01-01 07:10:13
18  2000      1    1  10:57:24  2000-01-01 10:57:24
19  2000      1    1   7:54:38  2000-01-01 07:54:38
```

Comment: thanks. However, this did not work- there are a few records with the string value "UNKNOWN", which is presenting an error for the whole function

Comment: you add in argument in your `pd.to_datetime(...,errors='coerce')` @nickp